# Bluetooth Headphones don't connect sound after turning on. Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

Everytime I turn turn on my headphones they connect but not as a playback device. It's not even available in the list of devices.

Turning off and on the bluetooth on my laptop always fixes the issue. Headset appears as playback device and windows switches to it automatically.

My device is Bluedio T5 headphones. And OS is Windows 10.

What I've tried so far:

1. Checked bluetooth services
   [image: bluetooth services]
2. Tried disabling **Microsoft Bluetooth Emulator**, **Microsoft Bluetooth LE Emulator** devices one by one and both of them. Didn't help.
3. Checked if all drivers are up to date - they are.

What else can I try?

p.s. my laptop doesn't have a button for BT, so I have to go to settings everytime to connect my headphones.